# Google PHP Client Library - invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

Whenever the pageviews I am retrieving has 0 pageviews, I receive the error `invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.

How am I supposed to prevent this error from occurring?

Here's my code:

```
        $parameters = array(
            'filters' => 'ga:pagePath==/about'
            'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
            'metrics' => 'ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews',
            'sort' => '-ga:pageviews'
        );

        $data = self::$analytics->data_ga->get(
            'ga:100174927',
            date("Y-m-d", $start),
            date("Y-m-d", $finish),
            'ga:visits',
            $parameters
        );

        $analytics = array(
            'pageviews'       => 0,
            'uniquePageviews' => 0
        );

        // This is the foreach loop that is creating the error:

        foreach ($data->getRows() as $key => $row)
        {    
            $analytics['pageviews']       += $row[1];
            $analytics['uniquePageviews'] += $row[2];
        }

        return $analytics;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do extensive checking like below:

```
if($data && is_array($data->getRows())){
    foreach ($data->getRows() as $key => $row)
    {    
        $analytics['pageviews']       += $row[1];
        $analytics['uniquePageviews'] += $row[2];
    }
}
```

$data may not be set in some cases causes foreach to complain.